# Pygame. Mysterious error. Event referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a python space shooter game with pygame.

**The error I am getting is: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment**.

It is mysterious, because **sometimes it appears** and breaks my program, **and sometimes it doesn't**. There is no pattern to the error occurrences, it just happens randomly out of nowhere.

I could run the program 2 times, and it would work fine, but then I run it again, and it gives this error.

The code that I am showing is a very simplified version of the real program, but it still produces the same error.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 660
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game!")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()

def message_to_screen(msg, colour, x, y):#This function is used to display messages to the game display.
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render(msg, True, colour)
    gamedisplay.blit(text, (x,y))


def start_screen():    
    global intro_running
    intro_running = True    

    while intro_running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                quit_game()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quit_game()
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    main_game_loop()

        gamedisplay.fill(WHITE)

        message_to_screen("start screen: press \"a\" to start", RED, 200, 200)

        pygame.display.update()#Updating the display.



def main_game_loop():
    intro_running = False#I make intro_running equal False here so that when this subprogram starts, the start_screen subprogram will end

    running = True

    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)#Makes the mouse invisible.

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                quit_game()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quit_game()

        gamedisplay.fill(GREEN)

        message_to_screen("Main game will be here", RED, 200, 200)

        all_sprites.draw(gamedisplay)

        all_sprites.update(event)#The event parameter needs to be passed, because some sprites in the group need it to check for events.

        pygame.display.update() 


start_screen()
```

**The full error is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Home/Documents/Python/pygame/test game/re-creation.py", line 106, in <module>
    start_screen()
  File "C:/Users/Home/Documents/Python/pygame/test game/re-creation.py", line 64, in <module>
    main_game_loop()
  File "C:/Users/Home/Documents/Python/pygame/test game/re-creation.py", line 98, in <module>
    all_sprites.update(event)#All sprites will be updated, each frame.
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sprites probably doesn't need the event argument but it's your game...you can easily fix this by placing it inside the event loop, since your error was caused because `event` was never defined during the first iteration of the while loop since there wasn't any event therefore the variable `event` was never generated.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        quit_game()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit_game()
    all_sprites.update(event) # this will guarantee that there's an event
```

But you can also consider doing this to make sure the sprite will always get updated:

```
class mysprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # example sprite class
    def __init__(self, event = None): # allow the event to have a default None argument 
        if event is None:
            # do stuff without the event
            return 
        # do stuff with the event


# the event loop snippet
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        quit_game()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit_game()
    all_sprites.update(event) # this will guarantee that there's an event
all_sprites.update() # without the event outside of the event loop in the while loop, where the all_sprites.update(event) used to be in your example, so the sprites will always get updated
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. This will help avoid many headaches in the future. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was provided in the other answer (**you have to apply what is suggested there)** there are also other causes of trouble with Pygame:

Pygame mysterious errors could have something to do with what else is going on the computer. I run your script thousand times without any error, BUT ... I witnessed while using a screenshot utility to capture the Pygame window a  freezing display to a degree that I had to reboot the computer (but only if special timing of closing the Pygame window and doing the screenshot came together). From this experience I suggest in case the advice given in the other answer doesn't prevent your game from crash for what reason ever:

> CHECK which of the applications running in background or foreground may have interfere with Pygame.

It could maybe be easy to detect as there are times the error occurs and times at which it doesn't, but if in addition a special timing of events of the application which interfere with Pygame is necessary for the error to occur it could be very hard to find.

There is no guarantee that this will solve your problem, but maybe it can.

If you want to witness yourself that Pygame handling of events and refreshing the display is not well designed just run a very simple Pygame application doing nothing else as showing an empty window with FPS of one frame per second (`FPSclock = pygame.time.Clock() -> FPSclock.tick(1)`). If on your box happens the same as on mine you will see the CPU being extremely busy with Pygame. Pygame is just a TOY - don't expect from it too much ...

Maybe you can find out how to modify your code to avoid that the special error occurs, BUT this is with high probability a kind of lottery game. I suppose there is no way to make Pygame run 100% safe from errors and problems under any circumstances. If you want that, switch to another known as stable and mature gaming engine.

It's life - if you gain something on one side you loose some on the other side.  There is sure a price to pay for the ease of programming games with Pygame - maybe you can arrange yourself with accepting that it is not a problem if occasionally a mystic error comes out of nowhere?